# Cannot get query results to display--php/mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form action="send_post.php" method="post">  
   <p>A: <input type="text" name="A">  
   <p>B: <input type="text" name="B">                                       
   <p><input type="submit">    
</form>     
<?php    
    $db = "localhost"; $usr = "blah1"; $pword = "blah2"; $dbname = "blah3"; 
    -----connects to server ok -------            
    $A = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['A']);  
    $B = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['B']);   
    $query="SELECT * FROM blah4 where A=$A and B=$B";     
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn, $query);         
    echo $sql;                                                
    $conn->clos();                                                                 
?>
```

What does it take to display the data from the db?

Comment: You need to show all your code. this really does not help us.

Comment: You should really [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) the SQL steatment. More secure than `mysqli_real_escape_string`!

Answer (score 1):

Your query  string is not properly formatted

```
<form action="send_post.php" method="post">  
   <p>A: <input type="text" name="A"> </p> 
   <p>B: <input type="text" name="B"> </p>                                     
   <p><input type="submit">    </p>
</form>     
<?php    
    $db = "localhost"; $usr = "blah1"; $pword = "blah2"; $dbname = "blah3"; 
    -----connects to server ok -------            
    $A = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['A']);  
    $B = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['B']);   
    $query="SELECT * FROM blah4 where A='$A' and B='$B'";     
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn, $query);         
    echo $sql;                                                
    $conn->close();                                                                 
?>
```

or

```
  $query="SELECT * FROM blah4 where A='".  $A ,"' and B='" .$B ."'";
```

you have also not closed `</p>`

and

```
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on your not actually getting the data from the db try this

```php
$row->mysqli_result::fetch_object($query);
```

then you can get certain fields like if u had a username field

```php
username = $row->username;
```

then you could display username like

```
echo $username;
```